# Combinatorics problemo

Tags: combinatorics

Five people are preparing for a Christmas party. They organize a draw to decide who will have to buy a present for whom. On each of five tickets the name of one person is written. Next the tickets are being drawn. A draw is succesful if nobody draws the ticket with his own name. How many succesful draws are possible?

This is easy enough to do by hand, but this seems to be a combinatorics problem which can be generalized for n people. How can I find a way of doing this for n people using combinatorics/probability (in other words, how can I do this problem with combinatorics/probability)?

Comment: The general notion here is that of [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @ArthurFischer, make that into an answer (add a bit more, perhaps). There isn't much more to be said on the matter.

Comment: If I knew much more about the topic I wouldn't have just left a comment.  And I really have nothing to add that cannot be obtained in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying combinatorial notion for this problem is that of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  Just as $n!$ denotes the total number of permutations of an $n$-element set, $\{ 1 , \ldots , n \}$, the value $D_n$ denotes the total number of permutations of $\{ 1 , \ldots , n \}$ which leave no elements fixed.  (In certain places you will see the notation $!n$ used instead, but as Douglas S. Stones remarks in a comment below, this notation may lead to ambiguity and is not very common in the literature.)

[The linked Wikipedia article says more about this topic than I know.]

Comment: May I note, the notation $!n$ is rarely used outside of the Wikipedia article.  It's silly notation: for example, what does $n!n$ mean?

Comment: @Douglas: Would $D(n)$ or $D_n$ (or similar) be the preferred notation?  I saw $!n$ in both Wikipedia and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) and figured it was pretty common/standard.

Comment: Yes, they're both quite standard.

Comment: There is also the notation $n¡$, found in *Concrete Mathematics*.

Comment: @Douglas: Thanks.  I'll edit the answer presently.

Comment: @Brian: If there was a nice "inverted exclamation mark" symbol available I would personally like to use it here; it does seem more _deranged_.

Comment: I use the Windows utility [Unichars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unichars/), which actually has it among the preset special characters.

Comment: @Brian: I meant the way it actually looks on my screen; to me the inverted exclamation mark doesn't have quite the same fullness as the regular exclamation mark.

Comment: I wondered whether you were talking about the aesthetics, since I agree that it’s a bit skinny, but I couldn’t do anything about that problem!